# No exact matches in reference to static method 'buildExpression' swift

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm a beginner in swift and I'm coding some kind of streaming app. I already had problems playing a video locally, which I solved by changing the button that was supposed to play the video at the base by a button that redirects to another swift file. This second file is then used to play the video. However, I use a json file to sort everything related name, image and video. So I'm looking for a way to make sure that when I'm on a certain program, my program can play the correct video by looking for the associated program/video name or id combination in the json file. In this case, a program looks like this in json:

````
"id": "EDCD038C-036F-4C40-826F-61C88CD84DDD",
                "name": "Best ouf",
                "photoCredit": "Image - Petite",
                "mainPicture": "20230331_143548",
                "price": 6,
                "video": "denoise filml de term 2",
                "restrictions": ["G", "V"],
                "description": "Sweet, fluffy, and served piping hot, our French toast is flown in fresh every day from Maple City, Canada, which is where all maple syrup in the world comes from. And if you believe that, we have some land to sell you…" ```
````

So i would like my program to know which video to play according to program name or id.
this is my program that displays the content of the requested program thanks to the json file:

```
    struct ItemDetail: View {
    let item: MenuItem
    @EnvironmentObject var order: Order
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack{
                Image(item.mainPicture)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            }
            Text(item.description)
                .padding()
            
            NavigationLink(destination: ItemVideo()) {
                                Text("watch")
                            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            Spacer()
            
        }
        .navigationTitle(item.name)
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        
    }
}



struct ItemDetail_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            ItemDetail(item: MenuItem.example)
                .environmentObject(Order())
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the program that allows you to launch the video following the button of the previous program:

```
import AVKit
import SwiftUI
var strVideos = String().self
let menu = Bundle.main.decode([MenuSection].self, from: "menu.json")
var body: some View {
    ForEach(menu) { section in
        Section(section.name) {
            ForEach(section.items) { item in
                strVideos = item.video
            }
        }
    }
}
        struct ItemVideo: View {
            let videoUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: strVideos, ofType: "mov")!)
            
            var body: some View {
                VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: videoUrl)) // 3
            }
            
        }
```

but the line strVideos = item.video show this error : No exact matches in reference to static method 'buildExpression' swift

Thanks in advance to anyone who will take the time to help me.

Comment: It is a typo somewhere, comment out sections until you don’t it.

Comment: The code you show for your `... program that allows you to launch the video...` is not enclosed in a 
  `struct xxxx: View { ...}` as required. You cannot have such code without this.
  Also you need to understand that `ForEach(...)` are views, not "normal" for loops. In those `ForEach(...)` 
  you **must** return some `View`, not assign some variables.
You need to read the **very basics** of `SwiftUI`, see for example: [SwiftUI tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/).

Comment: Ok i didn’t know apple did a complete tutorial. Anyway thank you so much for you answer.

Comment: For any future viewers who run into this: **this is a misleading error message**. This occurs when some part of code within the view code has _some_ error which is incorrectly reported as this "no exact matches thing". It might be a function parameter type is wrong, or some other error. To fix it, as @loremipsum stated, comment out parts until you isolate the line with the real error, or alternatively copy the broken parts to the top-level until you identify the real error.

Answer (score 2):

In case you have a function to return `any View` for `SwiftUI` code and your getting the error :

```
func getView() -> any View { ... }

var body: some View {
  List {
     ForEach(rows, id: \.id) { row in
         getView()
     }
  }
}
```

> No exact matches in reference to static method 'buildExpression' swift

, change `any View` to `some View` and add `@ViewBuilder` right before method declaration:

```
@ViewBuilder
func getView() -> some View { 
 if someCondition {
   Text("Hello")
 } else {
  Text("Bye")
 }
}
```

if you need to know more about 'some' and 'any' visit this link: [some vs any](https://www.donnywals.com/whats-the-difference-between-any-and-some-in-swift-5-7/)